# SICK: S3000: We got a I/O data packet we dont know what to do with it

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to establish communication with the laser scanner SICK S3000 (S30A-6011GB) through package s3000_laser (http://wiki.ros.org/s3000_laser) via RS422. After starting node `roslaunch s3000_laser.launch` I get the following response:

```
[ WARN] [1487759023.721179844]: S3000: We got a I/O data packet we dont know what to do with it
```

Used port dev/ttyUSB0 is correct. Baudrate (500000) is identical to the configuration of the laserscaner. I also used: sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0. In rostopic list i have topics: /scan , /tf and /tf_static. I tried to visualize data in rviz but without success.
I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 - ROS Kinetic.

I suppose it will be necessary to set the type of data sent by the sensor, so that they match the expected type. However, I can not figure out what they should contain the required data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255388/sick:-s3000:-we-got-a-i/o-data-packet-we-dont-know-what-to-do-with-it/) by [alex_wwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25926/alex_wwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Sick S3000 can be configured to ouptu different kinds of data: I/O, measurement (i.e. ranges) and reflector.
The driver apparently only handels the measurement data. I/O is irrelevant here.

You need to configure your driver to only output the measurements, see the [Sick telegram listing, p.46](https://www.sick.com/media/dox/2/92/892/Telegram_listing_S3000_Standard_Advanced_Professional_Remote_S300_Standard_Advanced_Professional_de_en_IM0022892.PDF) and the manual (did not quickly find the good link) on how to configure it. (Note you need to configure the scanner itself, not the driver or anything...)

(Few hints from my experience: continuous data ouput, only measurement, no I/O data, 1 telegram, specify no range fields)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1